# angular 7 start from VSC does not show index.html on chrome

Tags: angular, localhost, angular7

I open a **angular**7 project in **Visual Studio Code**,
I start the project with **F5**,
**Chrome** opens, but I get only a white page with error **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**.
That error appears, when my internet connection is not right, but I want to work locally on localhost.
What could cause that problem?

Thanks for help,
Frank

launch.json:

```
{
linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }  ] 
}
```

URL at my browser: *http://localhost:8080/*

Comment: Can you try load it with ng serve? Then try to call it via the "curl" command (like this : "curl localhost:4200").

Comment: both does not work.

Comment: can you try to open a new project with the "ng new" command and then "ng serve" and check localhost:4200?

Comment: @Rotemya  Yes, when I create a new project, that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Frank Mehlhop,

I think its look like you have set port number on which you run your application.
I mean generally we run angular application with 4200 port so you have to set 4200 instead of 8080.

Then it will work.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried with 4200, but also this port does not work.

Comment: 4200 is your application port ?

Comment: What you mean with "is your application port"? I set the port 4200 in the launch.json and I start the app. Browsr opens with localhost:4200. By the way, I think 8080 should work also.

Comment: I found out that the node_modules has been missing. But also with them is the same Problem.

Comment: @FrankMehlhop. The basic part number is not based on launch. Jason. Launch. Jason used for debugging. In this file you have to set your basic port which is 4200.

Comment: @FrankMehlhop, If you want to set 8080 then you have to run projects using "ng serve --port 8080".

Answer (score 0):

I had to use *ng serve* instead of F5.
Width *ng serve* I got also the message, that *node-sass* was missing.
After installing it all works. (*npm install node-sass*)